# Microsoft builds and continuous deployment - Large number of machines

Tags: sccm

Given:

- Multiple client-server applications across hundreds of servers and thousands of clients.
- TFS 2012 for source control and automated builds.
- SCCM 2012 as the deployment technology.

Is System Centre Orchestrator 2012 the most appropriate tool to facilitate production ready TFS builds to be pushed to SCCM for deployment?

Why?
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is No.

It seems that if you want a new version of an application in SCCM 2012 you can use [Application Supersedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682071.aspx)

...So in theory I could detect the drop of a new production .msi in a folder and then automate the supersedence with powershell.

Now I am thinking this is NOT a good idea for production in my environment, **really this question was me thinking by writing things out**.  I am attracted to the idea of continuous deployment, but not to production (in my environment).

Comment: I believe application supersedence only applies to sandboxed applications, not packages. It sounds like you want to version control packages, which isn't a bad idea, but the supersedence feature only applies to applications, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682125.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I was not thinking about version control of 'packages' - I think that would be handled by the build system.  I was thinking about continuous deployment of applications.